# ¿Cómo actualizar un campo en laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, tablas

Estoy tratando de actualizar un campo de una tabla en laravel 5., pero en vez de actualizarlo simplemente agrega uno nuevo. También me pasa que cuando busco el registro a través del método show no me devuelve nada. La tabla stories es una tabla nueva, la acabo de crear y su controlador es el único que me está dando problemas.

```
public function update(Request $request, storie $storie)
    {
        $storie->fill($request->only([
            'descripcion_history'=>'string|max:200',
        ]));
        if($storie->isClean()){

            return $this->errorResponse('Debe enviar al menos  un dato para cambiar',409);
        }
        $storie->save();
        return response()->json(['mensaje'=>'se actualizo correctamente','codigo'=>'202'],202);
    }
```

Comment: si en el fill no informas el id del registro a actualizar, siempre va a dar de alta uno

Comment: Hola , gracias por la respuesta . ese ID no lo resuelve con la inyección implícita del modelo ?  en los parametros de la funcion update ?  utilizo el mismo script en otros controladores y ninguno me da ese problema. no entiendo por que no funciona.

Comment: Pon alguna otra función update de otro controlador y sus respectivas rutas. Además, podrías añadir los dos modelos para comparar

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
$storie->where('Id',$request['tu_input_id'])
       ->update(['descripcion_history'=>$request['tu_input_descripcion']]);
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $subcat = request()->input('id_subcategoria');
        $prudctos = DB::table('productos')->where('id_subcategoria', $subcat);
        $prudctos->update(['descuento'=>$request['porcentaje']]);
```

Yo lo hago asi, primero obtengo en la variable $subcat el ide de la subcategoria y despues busco en la tabla de producto todos aquellos que tienen esa misma subcategoria y mas abajo con update() actualiza el campo descuento con el descuento previamente enviado de un formulario con $request